# What helm syntax does Istio use for their `sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml` file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

To be specific, here is the permalink to the relevant line of code: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/e3a376610c2f28aef40296aac722c587629123c1/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml#L84

> {{ "[[ .ProxyConfig.ZipkinAddress ]]" }}

The `[[` and `]]` seems alien to me, and in the helm chart developer guide doc [here](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#the-chart-template-developer-s-guide), it doesn't show any example or documentation about `[[` and `]]` syntax.

Also, when I tried to render my istio installation (using `helm template` command), the `{{ "[[ .ProxyConfig.ZipkinAddress ]]" }}` part only rendered as `[[ .ProxyConfig.ZipkinAddress ]]`. So I guess that `[[` and `]]` is not part of helm template syntax. My guess it would be internal istio's related syntax, which I don't know what exactly it is.

Any idea?

Comment: Interesting question. For what it's worth you can also see this in the `sidecar-injector` at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/istio/noauth/istio.yaml#L914 That maps to this dockerfile https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pilot/docker/Dockerfile.proxyv2#L32 and this go code https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/d28eb4d2ed4d07f06816169d6217efc79082002e/pilot/cmd/pilot-agent/main.go#L140 I don't know this codebase but I guess what we are seeing is yaml that is inside a ConfigMap that istio uses for creating sidecar proxies that are injected into Pods.

Comment: Yes you are correct @RyanDawson. I posted the answer below by linking to the original answer in the Istio's google group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer after posting the same question on the Istio's google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/istio-users/0dfU_y06n1Q). Without discrediting the author who answering me in the google group, the answer is yes it is a template of a template. The template syntax is used by sidecar injection described in here: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection/#template